# How to get folder name in which image is saved in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the name of the folder in which an image is saved

```
String imgFolder=ip.getParent();
```

`imgFolder` gives the full path like: `/storage/emulated/0/Wild`.

I only need `Wild`.

How to get the folder name of the image only?

Comment: `ip.getParentFile().getName()`

Comment: Have you solved this ? or still there is some issue left ?

Comment: @Mike M  Thannks `ip.getParentFile.getName()`  Worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this

```
 String folderName = imgFolder.substring(imgFolder.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

OR

```
ip.getParentFile().getName();
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer but i tried `ip.getParentFile().getName()` and it worked

Comment: @haiderrathore Ohh that also works fine. Both will solve the issue. I have added your solution too in answer. Now this will help others too. You are most welcome.